# How to select only the row with the latest date, in a set of groups of rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a historic error in our code. In a table where many different records are updated with new information over time, sometimes a new row will be created where an existing row should have been updated.

On subsequent queries, data from *both* rows is loaded into a single row our UI, and the data from the original record gets stuck there, because all future updates are saved to the new row, and data is eternally loaded from the older record, with no way to save back to it.

I have a query that returns data in the form `ID`, `ErrorGroupID`, `LastUpdatedDate`. This gives me all the groups of rows where this has happened.

So:

```
ID   |ErrorGroupID|LastUpdatedDate
----------------------------------
1    |1           |01/01/2000
2    |1           |01/01/2001
3    |2           |01/01/2002
4    |2           |01/01/2003
5    |3           |01/01/2004
6    |3           |01/01/2005
7    |3           |01/01/2006
```

I need to delete all of the rows with a particular `ErrorGroupID`, except the row with the highest date value in each group.

My SQL-fu appears to have deserted me. How do I get the ID values of the rows I need to delete?

Comment: If you want, post your original query which brings these values to you, then we may help you to solve the problem using one statement only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following query

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID
        , ErrorGroupID, LastUpdatedDate
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ErrorGroupID ORDER BY LastUpdatedDate DESC ) AS rownum
    FROM theTable
)
DELETE theTable 
FROM theTable
JOIN cte ON theTable.ErrorGroupID = cte.ErrorGroupID
WHERE cte.Rownum>1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly delete it:

```
delete from table
where
    ErrorGroupID = 1 
    and LastUpdatedDate < 
    (
        select 
            max(LastUpdatedDate)
        from
            table
        where
            ErrorGroupID = 1
    )
```

Or just change `delete from table` to `select ID from table` if you really prefer to get the IDs instead of just delete it.

To comprehend all groups (ErrorGroupID) at same time, use a IN clause or join this query to your original one.